# NSUrlSession reset(completionHandler:)

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

What happens to the current tasks present in the session when we do reset(completionHandler:) on UrlSession.
Also if it cancels the current tasks then how do we wait for the completion of the current tasks before calling reset(completionHandler:)

Answer (score 0):

When you call URLSession `reset`, all running tasks continue to run.

A common use case to use `reset` is, where you want to clear all data associated to the signed-in user for example - a "sign-out" feature. Requests resumed *before* calling `reset` may use the *old* URL Credential store, but yet they may use the *new* URL cache when the response completes. This is certainly NOT what you want.

So, a more robust way to accomplish this is as follows:

- prevent new tasks to be started (avoiding any data race issues)
- clear all data associated to the old "session environment" - which may include access tokens and user data etc.
- cancel all running tasks (asynchronously - fire & forget), then
- call `reset`, then
- enable resuming tasks.

New tasks will use the new "session environment", previously resumed tasks will complete with a cancellation error.

The first bullet point is probably the most complex one, since you need to ensure that you even do not create requests using data associated to the *old* session environment. That may be solved using a network layer that has a feature where incoming high level "API requests" will be queued, and that queue can be suspended and resumed.